# wxpython open second frame on mouse click no responding

Tags: python, wxpython

env:python37,windows,wxpython

There's a main frame keep opening while app is running, now I'm trying to create a new frame on mouse right click, the new frame works good if I open it by button click, but if it is triggered by a mouse click event, it will hang and no responding. I'm thinking if there's something wrong with mouse listener, really appreciate if you have any idea.

here's the code detail:

```
import wx
import time
import win32api
from threading import Thread

class OtherFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Class used for creating frames other than the main one
    """

    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('yellow')
        self.Show()


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        btn = wx.Button(self, label='Create New Frame')
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_new_frame)
        self.frame_number = 1

        thread = Thread(target=self.monitorMouse, name='monitorMouse')
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    def monitorMouse(self):
        state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)  # Left button down = 0 or 1. Button up = -127 or -128
        state_right = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)  # Right button down = 0 or 1. Button up = -127 or -128

        while True:
            a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
            b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)

            if b != state_right:  # Button state changed
                state_right = b
                if b < 0:
                    print('Right Button Pressed')
                else:
                    print('Right Button Released')
                    self.on_new_frame(None)
            time.sleep(0.001)

    def on_new_frame(self, event):
        title = 'SubFrame {}'.format(self.frame_number)
        frame = OtherFrame(title=title)
        self.frame_number += 1


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Main Frame', size=(800, 600))
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If are determined to monitor the mouse using a thread, then I think that you are going to have to look at `wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()`.
From within the thread you would use `wx.PostEvent` to send the mouse event back to the main program.

However, `wxpython` already has the mouse events available to you, to which you can bind directly e.g.

```
import wx

class OtherFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('yellow')
        self.Show()

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        btn = wx.Button(self, label='Create New Frame')
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_new_frame)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.Left)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.Right)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DCLICK, self.on_new_frame)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.Quit)
        self.frame_number = 1

    def Quit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def Left(self, event):
        print("Left Button")
        event.Skip()

    def Right(self, event):
        print("Right Button")

    def on_new_frame(self, event):
        title = 'SubFrame {}'.format(self.frame_number)
        frame = OtherFrame(parent=self,title=title)
        self.frame_number += 1

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Main Frame', size=(800, 600))
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

As an aside, note the line

```
frame = OtherFrame(parent=self,title=title)
```

sending the `parent` allows all outstanding `OtherFrame's` to close when the main frame is closed.

Comment: I would just add that replacing `self.on_new_frame(None)` with `wx.CallAfter(self.on_new_frame, None)` seems to fix the problem by redirecting the flow back to the main thread

Comment: @user2682863 You may well be right about that, I don't run a windows OS, so I can't test it. You might want to post that as an answer. It may well be what the OP is looking for rather than my blurb!

Comment: @user2682863 it works, thank you! I found a link about the main thread and worker thread - item 4. https://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui

Comment: @Rolf of Saxony thank you, I monitor the whole screen since I want to get the selected text even not belong to wxpython main frame